# Macro with Iteration through URL

Tags: r

Having a problem creating a macro variable within an API call in R. I am trying to loop through a vector of zip codes and make an API call on that vector iteratively. Pretty unfamiliar with iterating through a R list that needs to be macro'd out.

Here is my code:

```
# creating a dataframe of 10 sample California zip codes to iterate through from database
zip_iterations<-sqlQuery(ch,"Select distinct zip from zip_codes where state='CA' limit 10",believeNRows="F")

# Calling the api to retrieve the JSON
json_file <- "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=**'MACRO VECTOR TO ITERATE'**
```

My goal is to go through the list of 10 zip codes in the dataframe by using a macro.

Comment: You'll have to explain what the form of the URL is supposed to be because as written this is pretty impossible to help you solve.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Not exactly sure what you mean by form of the URL but, it's a weather API call for JSON by zip code. Lets say I have zip codes 53555 and 76534. I'm looking to do something like a for loop. The zip= would usually have just an ordinary zip code like 53555, and I would get the weather for that zip, but I want that to = the macro I create, so it first calls 53555 then 76534 and loops through all rows in the dataframe...Just not exactly sure how to reference the macro within the double quotes of the URL I am pulling the JSON from.

Answer (score 0):

R doesn't use macros per se, but there are lots of alternative ways of doing what it sounds like you want to do. This version will return a character vector `json_file`, with each entry containing the body of the HTTP response for that zip code:

```
library("httr")
json_file <- character(0)
urls <- paste0("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=", zip_iterations)
for (i in seq_along(urls)) {
  json_file[i] <- content(GET(urls[i]), as = "text")
}
```

You can then parse the resulting vector into a set of R lists using, for example, `fromJSON()` from the jsonlite package, such as:

```
library("jsonlite")
lapply(json_file, fromJSON)
```

The result of that will be a list of lists.